# update mysql table with results from spatial query

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, spatial-query

I am using mysql to count the number of point features (shops) within a polygon feature (postsec).

The select query I have works fine, but I want to update table postsec with the generated results. The query I have is below:

```
select pc_sec, count(*) as count from shops 
join postsec on st_within(shops.SHAPE,postsec.SHAPE) 
where shops.shop_cat > 0 and shop_cat < 10 group by pc_sec
```

I have tried a number of methods for doing this e.g. update postsec set new_column = ([select query]) but can't seem to find the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
update postsec 
inner join 
(
   select pc_sec, count(*) as pseccount 
   from shops 
   join postsec on st_within(shops.SHAPE,postsec.SHAPE) 
   where shops.shop_cat between 1 and 9
   group by pc_sec
) x on x.pc_sec = postsec.id
set count_column = x.pseccount
```